# Android WorkManager fork single into multiple chains and join

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I want to set up the following work using WorkManager:

```
   A
   |
   v
 -----
|     |
v     |
B     v
|     D
v     |
C     |
|     |
 -----
   |
   v
   E
```

So first, `A` should should run, then `B` followed by `C` while `D` runs in parallel. After that, `E` should run.

Joining the two parallel chains before running `E` can be done with `WorkContinuation.combine()`. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to do the forking into two parallel chains after `A`. (It would be simple if the left chain containing `B` and `C` wasn't an actual chain of two requests but only a single request.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, the chain you want to build is not possible to implement with WorkManager. You can open a feature request on [WorkManager's issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197).

Going back to your chain, I wonder if it can be modified to fit into WorkManager API:

```
   A
   |
   v
 -----
|     |
v     |
B     v
|     D
|     |
 -----
   |
   v
   C
   |
   v
   E
```

In this case you need to handle with some logic the input merger into `C` so that it does what you expect, **this if you have data passed between the `Worker` classes**. But you maintain the same constraints (but in this case `C` requires that you terminate `D` before it is started).

In this case, following [WorkManager's documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work), you can have something like:

```
        val workRequestA = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SaveImageToFileWorker>().build()
        val workRequestB = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SaveImageToFileWorker>().build()
        val workRequestC = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SaveImageToFileWorker>()
                .setInputMerger(ArrayCreatingInputMerger::class.java)
                .build()
        val workRequestD = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SaveImageToFileWorker>().build()
        val workRequestE = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SaveImageToFileWorker>().build()

        var continution = workManager
                .beginWith(workRequestA)
                .then(listOf(workRequestB, workRequestD))
                .then(workRequestC)
                .then(workRequestE)
                .enqueue()
```

Comment: Thank you @pfmaggi! Good to know that my requirement is currently not possible. Also thank you for your proposed workaround which inspired me for the following solution: In my case the longer running work is `C`. So I will instead parallelize `C` and `D` and have `B` on its own after `A`.